# Mostrar diferentes Modals Boostrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, modal

Tengo una app en Bootstrap la cual tiene que mostrar diferentes modales en diferentes paginas. 
Para ello he pensado sacar dichos modales y tener cada uno en un archivo HTML de forma que después desde cada pagina pueda llamarlo para que se muestre.
Lo quiero hacer así para no tener que declarar en los diferentes HTML los mismos Divs con los modales de forma que si tengo que crear un HTML nuevo, no tenga que hacer un copy paste con todos los modales.

Resumen:
No consigo tener un modal en un HTML diferente y desde una función JS llamarlo.
Alguien ha hecho esto? Me podéis echar un cable?

Muchas gracias!

En el ejemplo de abajo, replico la pagina1.html, a lo que me refiero es, si por ejemplo en la pagina2.html necesito solo 2 de los 3 modales, me tocaria replicar el codigo de

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick='openModalOne()'>Open One</button>
        <button onclick='openModalTwo()'>Open Two</button>
        <button onclick='openModalThree()'>Open Three</button>
        <div class="modal fade" id="dialogError" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            ....
        </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="dialogInfo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            ....
        </div>
        <div class="modal fade" id="dialogConfirm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            ....
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Recomiendo que se lea esta **Documentacion:**
http://blog.hostdime.com.co/incluir-archivo-html-en-otro-html-con-la-etiqueta-import/

Comment: ¿Podrías crear un [mcve] para  ver tu código y poder ayudarte mejor?

Comment: Existen varias opciones, dependiendo de las herramientas que uses para desarrollar tu aplicación: Ajax, incluir un HTML en otro...

Comment: Acabo de editar la pregunta añadiendo un trozo de codigo de ejemplo.

Comment: Hola, ¿Qué hacen las funciones `openModal()` en tu código?

Answer (score 1):

A menos que estés ocupando un motor de plantillas que permita el uso de plantillas parciales (ej Twig, Handlebars) inevitablemente vas a tener que repetir cierto código en cada una de tus páginas.En otras palabras: debieras usar un motor de plantillas para facilitarte la vida.

Sin embargo, este comportamiento se podría emular **si insertaras el html de los modales dinámicamente mediante ajax**, y a su vez **llenases el contenido de cada modal dinámicamente usando ajax**, leyendo un atributo del botón que lo llamó:

Pensemos que en cada página pones, al pié de ésta, un script que inserte el div que contiene los modales y sus respectivos botones:

```
<body>
    <div>
       Contenido cualquiera
    </div>
    <div id="modales">

    </div>
    <script src="modales.js"></script>
</body>
```

A su vez. `modales.js` carga via ajax los botones que abren tu modal y el esqueleto mismo del modal, cuyo html se encuentra en un archivo distinto llamado (muy originalmente) `modales.html`

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.get('modales.html').then(function(content) {
      jQuery('#modales').empty().append(content);
    });
  });
```

En `modales.html` podrías tener el html que no quieres repetir una y otra vez:

```
<div id="modal-show-page" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<p>
  <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-show-page" data-href="exito.html">Modal de Éxito</a>

  <a class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-show-page" data-href="error.html">Modal de Error</a>
</p>
```

Si te fijas, tengo un solo contenedor modal, pero dos botones que lo abren. Cada botón tiene un atributo `data-href` que apunta a otro html que  voy a cargar dentro del modal abierto usando:

```
jQuery('#modales').find('#modal-show-page').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget);
    var href = button.data('href');
    var modal = $(this);
    jQuery.get(href).then(function(content) {
      modal.find('.modal-content').empty().append(content);
    });
  });
```

El contenido de `modales.html` no existe antes de cargar ese html por ajax, de manera que estoy usando delegación de eventos usando el contenedor `#modales` que sí existe desde un comienzo.

[Te dejo un plunkr funcionando.](https://plnkr.co/edit/P6qB5tIxXdGBzYonAE6p?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Lo más sencillo (en mi opinión) es que hagas en la parte del html donde quieras poner la modal `<?php include 'modalquesea.php';?>` y en ese archivo externo .php pones el código de la modal. Deberas correrlo en un servidor local, no te funcionará si simplemente abres el archivo con el navegador.

Tambien puedes hacerlo con ajax, como te comentan, pero si no va a ser dinámico y siempre cargará la misma modal en la misma pagina yo creo que es más "limpio" hacerlo con php.

Comment: No sé si el OP está utilizando PHP...

Answer (score 0):

Estoy asumiendo que estás usando Bootstrap 3.

Una buena opción es crearte un `div` contenedor en tu página principal donde se van a cargar tus `htmls` estáticos con los distintos modales:

```
<div id="miModal" class="modal fade text-center">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

En dicho modal cargarás los diferentes `htmls` diciendo que el `target` es tu `div` genérico y que el `href` es la página que quieres cargar en tu modal:

```
<button href="pagina1.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miModal">Open One</button>
<button href="pagina2.html" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#miModal">Open Two</button>
```

Además, cuando se oculta una modal tendrás que borrar tanto la modal en sí como el contenido (si no, al crear la nueva modal, se mantendrá unos instantes el contenido anterior de la modal):

```
$(this).removeData('bs.modal'); //Borramos la modal
$(this).find(".modal-content").empty(); //Vaciamos su contenido
```

Te dejo una demo funcionando:

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/SSJBvBUkjPiTs4eXZ33Y)